# How to check for Is not Null And Is not Empty string in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we  check in a SQL Server `WHERE` condition whether the column is not null and not the empty string (`''`)?

Answer (score 482, accepted):

If you only want to match "" as an empty string

```
WHERE DATALENGTH(COLUMN) > 0
```

If you want to count any string consisting entirely of spaces as empty

```
WHERE COLUMN <> ''
```

Both of these will not return `NULL` values when used in a `WHERE` clause. As `NULL` will evaluate as `UNKNOWN` for these rather than `TRUE`.

```
CREATE TABLE T 
  ( 
     C VARCHAR(10) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO T 
VALUES      ('A'), 
            (''),
            ('    '), 
            (NULL); 

SELECT * 
FROM   T 
WHERE  C <> ''
```

Returns just the single row `A`. I.e. The rows with `NULL` or an empty string or a string consisting entirely of spaces are all excluded by this query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d933/1)

Comment: Why not `WHERE COALESCE(column, '') <> ''`?

Comment: Because if `column` has an index, then your query will probably not use it

Comment: Im not sure but if you write WHERE COL<>'' this will propable make table scan instead of seek.

Comment: @mr R - Incorrect - SQL Server can do a seek with two range predicates for that. `< ''` and `> ''` - though unless there are a large number of rows with the empty string value this might not help much.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between `<> ''` vs `!=''` ?

Comment: @Caltor - no they both get resolved to the same symbol during parsing and so are entirely indistinguishable https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155670/3690

Answer (score 185):

```
WHERE NULLIF(your_column, '') IS NOT NULL
```

---

Nowadays (4.5 years on), to make it easier for a human to read, I would just use

```
WHERE your_column <> ''
```

While there is a temptation to make the null check explicit...

```
WHERE your_column <> '' 
      AND your_column IS NOT NULL
```

...as @Martin Smith demonstrates in the accepted answer, it doesn't really add anything (and I personally shun SQL nulls entirely nowadays, so it wouldn't apply to me anyway!).

Answer (score 31):

in basic way

```
SELECT *
FROM [TableName]
WHERE column_name!='' AND column_name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: No need to check that it is not NULL, the column_name !='' will do that. So expression can be simplified.

Answer (score 21):

You can use either one of these to check null, whitespace and empty strings.

```
WHERE COLUMN <> '' 

WHERE LEN(COLUMN) > 0

WHERE NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN)), '') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 20):

Coalesce will fold nulls into a default:

```
COALESCE (fieldName, '') <> ''
```

Answer (score 9):

An index friendly way of doing this is:

```
where (field is not null and field <> '')
```

If there aren't many rows or this field isn't indexed, you can use:

```
 where isnull(field,'') <> ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check:     where value > ''   -- not null and not empty

```
-- COLUMN CONTAINS A VALUE (ie string not null and not empty) :
-- (note: "<>" gives a different result than ">")
select iif(null    > '', 'true', 'false'); -- false (null)
select iif(''      > '', 'true', 'false'); -- false (empty string)
select iif(' '     > '', 'true', 'false'); -- false (space)
select iif('    '  > '', 'true', 'false'); -- false (tab)
select iif('
'                  > '', 'true', 'false'); -- false (newline)
select iif('xxx'   > '', 'true', 'false'); -- true
--
--
-- NOTE - test that tab and newline is processed as expected:
select 'x   x' -- tab
select 'x

x' -- newline
```

Answer (score -1):

For some kind of reason my NULL values where of data length 8. That is why none of the abovementioned seemed to work. If you encounter the same problem, use the following code:

```
--Check the length of your NULL values
SELECT DATALENGTH(COLUMN) as length_column
FROM your_table

--Filter the length of your NULL values (8 is used as example)
WHERE DATALENGTH(COLUMN) > 8
```

Comment: This was presumably a string containing the word `NULL` of `NVARCHAR` datatype, not an actual `NULL`. To find those strings you can just use `= N'NULL'` as they are just regular strings!

Answer (score -1):

check this way
where Ph != '' and Ph = '123456780'

Comment: WHERE LEN(Ph) > 0

Answer (score -1):

Check the not null condition and empty string in SQL command is use 'is null / not null' and '!='.
please try this sample pattern script:

```
SELECT * FROM [Employee] 
WHERE
    EMail is not null -- not null check
    and Email != '' -- not empty check
```