# Dropdownlist binded data code behind shows blank rows

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net, VB code behind web with access database. i am using this code to bind data.

```
Dim comd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID1 FROM [Tak1] Where Section_='" + sectxt.Text + "' and status_='Open' and ID1<>""", con1)
Dim daa As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dss As New DataSet()
daa.Fill(dss)
DropDownList3.Items.Clear()
DropDownList3.DataSource = dss
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "ID1"
DropDownList3.DataBind()
DropDownList3.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select", "NA"))
```

Database is having some rows blank in ID1 field. data gets bind but there is blank space as there are some rows with blank ID1 as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to write:

```
Dim comd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID1 FROM [Tak1] Where Section_='" + sectxt.Text + "' and status_='Open' and ID1<>""""", con1)
```

or, alternatively (and preferably),

```
Dim comd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID1 FROM [Tak1] Where Section_='" + sectxt.Text + "' and status_='Open' and ID1<>''", con1)
```

(You may have forgotten to add all the quotes you wanted, since `""` is an escape for `"`)

For a similar question see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660203/is-not-null-and-empty-string)