# Comparing empty string with null value - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare two columns, and am hitting issues when comparing `NULL` against an empty string. Put simply, this is what I'm looking at.

```
DECLARE @EmptyString VARCHAR(20) = '', -- Could have valid VARCHAR data, empty string, or NULL
        @Null VARCHAR(20) = Null; -- Could have valid VARCHAR data, empty string, or NULL

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @EmptyString != @Null THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS EmptyStringVsNull
```

In this case, because we all know that an empty string and a null column value are different, I would hope to see the result come back  as 'Pass', however it doesn't.

From Martin's asnwer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8660220/6236042), he explains that that a comparison like this results to `UNKNOWN`, rather than `TRUE` or `FALSE`, which clarifies the reason I am seeing these results, but I need find a solution to this. I know there *must* be a simply way around this that I'm missing...

I know that there are a few built in functions such as `ISNULL()` and `NULLIF()`, however I don't know if these can help in this situation...

#### ISNULL()

If we use the `ISNULL()` function to set null values to an empty string, then the comparison wont work as an empty string is equal to an empty string, for example

```
DECLARE @EmptyString VARCHAR(20) = '',
        @Null VARCHAR(20) = Null;

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@EmptyString, '') != ISNULL(@Null, '') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS EmptyStringVsNull
```

This also returns 'FAIL', so this is a no go. I could always use `ISNULL` to convert this to a different string, but this still isn't suitable, as the empty string may have a different value which by chance could match whatever we decide to convert null values to.

#### NULLIF()

```
DECLARE @EmptyString VARCHAR(20) = '',
        @Null VARCHAR(20) = Null;

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN NULLIF(@EmptyString, '') != NULLIF(@Null, '') THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS EmptyStringVsNull
```

If we use the `NULLIF()` function to convert empty strings to null, our comparison still doesn't return true. This is because, as explained in the linked post, comparing null values results in `UNKNOWN`.

With the simple SQL example above, how can I check that a `NULL` value is not equal to an empty string?

Comment: I've read your question twice and still don't understand what you are asking. Seems like you are confused as to what the `ISNULL` and `NULLIF` built in functions do.

Comment: I think you have confused yourself and everybody else with this question.  Can you create a logic table of all the combinations (A side and B side) with expected results and update your question with it included?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first example returns fail because you have the wrong operator. If you want to see if something equals something else you use `=`, not `!=`

Here is the code that proves that `NULL` can be compared to `''`:

```
DECLARE @EmptyString VARCHAR(20) = '',
        @Null VARCHAR(20) = Null;

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@EmptyString, '') = ISNULL(@Null, '') 
    THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' 
    END AS EmptyStringVsNull
```

It returns pass because you use `=`, not `!=`

Answer (score 3):

Just reverse the comparison:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @EmptyString = @Null THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Pass' END) as EmptyStringVsNull
```

The only complication is if you want two `NULL` values to be the same.  If so:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @EmptyString = @Null OR (@EmptyString IS NULL AND @Null IS NULL)
             THEN 'Fail' ELSE 'Pass'
        END) as EmptyStringVsNull
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @EmptyString VARCHAR(20) = '', -- Could have VARCHAR data, empty string, or NULL
        @Null VARCHAR(20) = Null; -- Could have VARCHAR data, empty string, or NULL

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN @EmptyString IS NOT  @Null THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS EmptyStringVsNull.
```

Because of ansi sql standard you can check for NUll value using IS NULL or IS NOT NULL  operator.

Comment: @Null is a parameter (I know) you can tell by the @ symbol in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is quicker and more "Pythonic" (easier to understand by someone else who reads your code) to evaluate to the same outcome on both sides of the equal sign:

```
DECLARE @EmptyString VARCHAR(20) = ''

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@EmptyString, '') != ''
         THEN 'Pass'
         ELSE 'Fail' END AS EmptyStringVsNull
GO
```

Both an EMPTY string and a true NULL value will yield TRUE for the search condition.

NOTE: It is not optimal, since good bussiness rules practices should clearly differenciate a NULL attribute from an EMPTY attribute.
i.e.

- spouse_field = NULL (I still don't have the information regarding entity X's marital status)
- spouse_field = '' *(empty)*: That specific entity is confirmed as single. Otherwise, a name would have shown up.