# Ruby on Rails and Querys (understanding Question)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table called Codes on my project.

```
irb(main):017:0> Code.new                                      
=> #<Code id: nil, company_id: nil, name: nil, employee_uuid: nil, employee_email: nil, redeemed_at: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

On my Database i have a total of 97994 Code entries.

```
irb(main):018:0> Code.all.count
(127.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes"
=> 97994
```

So, what i don't understand is the following.
So far i tested it with the name attribute.

```
irb(main):019:0> Code.where(name: "").count
(135.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE "codes"."name" = ?  [["name", ""]]
=> 0
irb(main):020:0> Code.where(name: " ").count
(18.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE "codes"."name" = ?  [["name", " "]]
=> 0
```

if the do the oposite Query it should give me the missing objects, on this case my total amount of codes.

```
irb(main):021:0> Code.where.not(name: "").count 
(116.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE ("codes"."name" != ?)  [["name", ""]]
=> 94652
irb(main):022:0> Code.where.not(name: " ").count
(19.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE ("codes"."name" != ?)  [["name", " "]]
=> 94652
```

But i get as a result 94652 instead of 97994 (from Code.all.count)

That makes me wonder. I did check what are the left codes:

```
irb(main):023:0> rest = Code.all - Code.where(name: "") - Code.where.not(name: "")
Code Load (1030.6ms)  SELECT "codes".* FROM "codes"
Code Load (16.1ms)  SELECT "codes".* FROM "codes" WHERE "codes"."name" = ?  [["name", ""]]
Code Load (489.1ms)  SELECT "codes".* FROM "codes" WHERE ("codes"."name" != ?)  [["name", ""]]
... a huge array was returned
irb(main):024:0> rest.last
=> #<Code id: 86217, company_id: 307, name: nil, employee_uuid: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", employee_email: "XXXXX@EMAIL.COM", redeemed_at: "2018-07-09 12:30:29", created_at: "2018-12-11 13:07:57", updated_at: "2018-12-11 13:07:57">
```

I was curious about this, so i checked one more thing:

```
irb(main):027:0> rest.last.name == ""
=> false
irb(main):028:0> rest.last.name != ""
=> true
```

so the rest.last.name is not "" (of course not, name is `nil`)

but still i get this

```
irb(main):025:0> Code.where(name: "").include? rest.last
Code Load (108.1ms)  SELECT "codes".* FROM "codes" WHERE "codes"."name" = ?  [["name", ""]]
=> false
irb(main):026:0> Code.where.not(name: "").include? rest.last
Code Load (365.9ms)  SELECT "codes".* FROM "codes" WHERE ("codes"."name" != ?)  [["name", ""]]
=> false
```

I always thought where something, and its negative will always make the total amount, meaning when something happen, and when this something does not happen would give us the always answer. `A + !A = 1`
Why am i seeing this? i cannot follow this.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Update Question to answer comments:

```
irb(main):002:0> Code.where(name: [nil, '']).count                                                   
(432.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE ("codes"."name" = '' OR "codes"."name" IS NULL)
=> 3342
```

and this number is exactly

```
irb(main):003:0> Code.all.count - Code.where.not(name: "").count
(315.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes"
(332.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "codes" WHERE ("codes"."name" != ?)  [["name", ""]]
=> 3342
```

Ok, so far i understand that SQL cannot compare to Nil or not Nil when i test if a string is empty. That means i need to either do the query with array `[nil, '']` or think in an other way..

Comment: Could you share the result of the following query? 
`Code.where(name: [nil, '']).count`

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because sql `!=` and `=` operators can't compare with NULL. For NULL comparison you need to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` or in ROR syntax

```
Code.where(name: [nil, '']).count
Code.where.not(name: [nil, '']).count
```

Comment: you mean that (in SQL) `!= ''` will never include the `== nil` results ?

Comment: @FilipeSantiago, exactly!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, The default value for `name` being stored in database is `NULL`. If you did not save `name` for a `code` entry in the database, it will be stored as `NULL` instead of an empty string `""`.

So, if you run the query `Code.where(name: "").count`, this will explicitly try to return only those rows that have a name equal to an empty string (`""`) and ignore all entries having name=`NULL` or `"  "`. This is `0` in your case

When you run the query `Code.where(name: [nil, '']).count`, you receive a result of `3342`, which is exactly equal to the difference between all rows in the table and the rows that do not have a name equal to an empty string (`Code.where.not(name: "").count`). Which proves that there are 3342 rows in the table that have `name` stored as `NULL`.

So, in order to avoid this situation, you can set default value of `""` (empty string) to your name attribute in the migration that is creating the Code table. This way, the results of your query to find entries where name is not present, i.e. (`Code.where(name: "").count`)  consistent.

### Update:

`Code.where.not(name: '')` will ignore records where `name = NULL` in database. Reason is the query that is formed:

`SELECT * FROM Codes WHERE name != "";`

This query explicitly tries to find those rows where name is not "", but in order to check if NULL exists or not, we have to write a query like the one below in SQL:

`SELECT * FROM Codes WHERE name IS NOT NULL;`

The above mentioned query is generated if we write `Codes.where.not(name: nil)` in ActiveRecord.

To implement both conditions that were mentioned above in the two different queries in a single query, we will use the following in ActiveRecord:

`Code.where.not(name: [nil, ""])`

This will generate the following query:

`SELECT * FROM "codes" WHERE AND (NOT (("codes"."name" = "" OR "codes"."name" IS NULL)))`

The above query ensures that we avoid records with both conditions of empty string and NULL-valued name in database.

Comment: My question here is more, why `Code.where.not(name: "")`does not include the codes that have the `name = nil` value.
I guess, when i try to search for a name that is not equal to "" SQL ( and not ruby/rails) think the name is already a NOT NIL value, and ignores it, or am i wrong here?

Comment: I have updated the answer under the `Update` heading to try to answer your question. Please have a look and let me know if this information is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries do not return records with **NULL** values when using a **where** clause.

Some additional resources:

- https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activerecord-s-where-not-and-nil
- [How to check for Is not Null And Is not Empty string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660203/how-to-check-for-is-not-null-and-is-not-empty-string-in-sql-server/8711916)