# How to make a stored function, where you return a value if it is not null?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

I want to make a Stored Function where, if the guest have made a reservation on a specific date it returns the email of the guest and if he hasn't it returns null.I want to use the pID and begindate for the Stored Function. Rooms with a begindate of 0000-00-00 arent booked yet. How do I do this?

My current database:

```
pID              |begindate    | enddate     |  mail 
------------------------------------------------------
COD12            | 2014-07-15  | 2014-07-18  | z@yahoo.com
COD400           | 2014-07-20  | 2014-07-21  | q@hotmail.com
COD12            | 0000-00-00  |             | 
COD600           | 2014-07-04  | 2014-07-12  | h@gmail.com
MOD10            | 0000-00-00  |             |
```

So I want to run the stored function:

```
SELECT Stored_Function('COD12','2014-07-15')
```

This returns:

```
| Stored_Function('COD12','2014-07-15')     |     
------------------------------------------
| 2014-07-15                                |
```

And this returns Null:

```
SELECT Stored_Function('COD12','2014-07-16')
```

```
| Stored_Function('COD12','2014-07-16')     |     
------------------------------------------
| Null                                      |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for Is not Null And Is not Empty string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660203/how-to-check-for-is-not-null-and-is-not-empty-string-in-sql-server)

Comment: @OmarSherif but that link refers a page for SQL Server.

Comment: 'stored Function. Rooms with a begindate of 0000-00-00 arent booked yet' - how is this relevant? And why would you have an email for rooms not booked?

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah that was my bad. It shouldnt have a mail

Comment: @Kryoke have you found solution?